# SQL / NetSuite: CASE (expr1) WHEN (> condition1) THEN outcome1 ... how to make it work?

Tags: sql, netsuite

(NetSuite) I'm doing a transaction search and if the amount of gallons for last trailing twelve months is within certain ranges of contract compliance, then apply scaled liquidated damages. We have at least 100,000 transaction each week.

I have this saved search working, but I want to make it faster & more elegant/simpler.

This is the current working solution :

```
   CASE
   WHEN (expr1 >= xx) THEN outcome1
   WHEN (expr1 >= yy) THEN outcome2
   etc .. etc
   ELSE alt-outcome
   END
```

"expr1" is an actual formula containing both "SUM" & CASE WHEN".

If the the current solution has to go through to "outcome4" then NetSuite times out because it has to calculate "expr1" separately four times (or more) and this takes too long.

However if I use the following then NetSuite only needs to calculate "expr1" once and thus no timing out & faster:

```
   CASE (expr1)
   WHEN (>= xx) THEN outcome1
   WHEN (>= yy) THEN outcome2
   etc .. etc
   ELSE alt-outcome
   END
```

However it always fails if I use ">", "<", ">=" or "<=" ... as in either (>= xx) or (>= yy) .. etc

How to make this work please?

Comment: Are you really sure expr1 is calculated several times? (A decent optimizer would have it done only once.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the result of expr1 down into a subquery and see if that helps. Be surprised if so, an optimizer should be able to recognize and consolidate redundant steps even with how you wrote it originally.

```
select 
       case when expr1_result > xx then outcome1
            when expr1_result > yy then outcome2
            ...
            else alt_outcome
        end as final_name
  from (
        select st.*,
               expr1(<args>) as expr1_result
          from some_table st
       )
```